# Where are the methods of the Iterator Interface actually implemented in the Collections Framework?

Tags: java, methods, iterator, implementation, iterable

Following the hierarchy of the Collections Framework in Java, I struggle to understand where these 2 methods of the Iterator Interface are being implemented.

```
boolean hasNext();

E next();
```

The other 2 methods

```
default void remove()

default void forEachRemaining(Consumer<? super E> action)
```

have default  implementations in the Iterator Interface itself (although they are probably overridden somewhere else too).

[image]

image source: https://www.javatpoint.com/collections-in-java

I know that depending on the hierarchy, for example Interface -> Interface -> Class, the implementation can be either in the interface itself as a default method or in the concrete class. But lets take for example the ArrayList, where in the whole hierarchy are the hasNext() and next() methods being implemented.

Comment: Each collection class almost always implements the `Iterator` with an own private inner class.

Answer (score 0):

`Collection` implements `Iterable` and `Iterable` has the method `iterator()` that returns the `Iterator` interface, so implementations dont have to implement the `Iterator` interface.

If you take `ArrayList` for example, it inherits `AbstractList` which implements `iterator` and that is used by different lists implementations.

Comment: For anyone that has read this answer and is still left feeling confused, I would suggest you learn about factory methods. That is what helped me understand this answer.